# How do I configure the RVM interpreter in TeamCity (automated build tool)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, teamcity

Whenever I build my project in TeamCity, I specify a "ruby environment configurator" build feature as follows:

[image: Config Settings for Ruby Env]

the build always fails with the following output:

```
RVM interpreter 'ruby-1.9.3' doesn't exist or isn't a file or isn't a valid RVM interpreter name.
```

I've tried changing the Gemset to `Gemfile` and changing "Interpreter Name:" to `ruby-1.9.3-p551` and `ruby-2.1.3` but no dice

Comment: known problem with TeamCity buildagent. Check their forums, it's full of it. Depends on which distro you're running as well as your Java installation and your TC version

Comment: Probably it is [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-32772). Please vote/watch and post build logs and 'rvm.rubies.list' build parameter value

Comment: as @NekoNova mentioned, it was a known TeamCity buildagent problem.  In our case, we fixed the problem by upgrading to Ruby 2.1.3 for the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing like you said, install ruby and update gems using

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
sudo gem update --system
```

Then restart your server.After that you can start building your project.Environment will be read automatically..